# How do I make the text in the header of my table not bold?

Tags: html, text, html-table, tableheader

I need to use a rowspan for my table, therefore I (believe) I must use a table header. However, using a table header makes my font bold, which is unwanted. For this HTML, how would I make sure the font in my table header isn't bold? Or, if it's possible, how can I use rowspan without using a table header?

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">Telephone:</th>
<td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 33):

Simply overhide the `font-weight` of the `th` element in CSS :

```
th{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

JSBin : http://jsbin.com/lizakatuwe/1/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need table header at all, you can use `rowspan` with `td` too. To make it not bold, override the `font-weight` in css to `normal`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <tr rowspan="2"><p style="font-weight:bold">Telephone:</p></tr>
<td>555 77 854</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I am using internal CSS for you, directly insert the font style inside your table.
Copy and pasta this code into your project, it will do the job.